# How to cut off the line in highcharts between two pointI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Is there anyway to cut off the chart line if the period of points exceeds a specific limit?

I mean, I want to cut off the chart if there is no data for a specific timespan.

[image]

in the picture above, I want to cut off that piece of chart.

Well I am using DotNet.Highcharts implementation for highcharts in .net, but I can Post the resulting javascript codes here :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
Chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { renderTo:'Chart_container', className: 'chart', defaultSeriesType: 'line', marginBottom: 55, marginRight: 130, zoomType: 'xy' }, 
    legend: { align: 'left', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', layout: 'vertical', verticalAlign: 'top', x: 20, y: 80 }, 
    plotOptions: { area: { lineWidth: 1, marker: { enabled: false, states: { hover: { enabled: true, radius: 5 } } }, shadow: false, zIndex: 2 }, line: { allowPointSelect: true, dashStyle: 'solid', lineWidth: 1, marker: { enabled: false } }, spline: { marker: { enabled: false }, zIndex: 1000 } }, 
    subtitle: { text: 'My chart', x: -20 }, 
    title: { text: 'My Chart' }, 
    xAxis: { gridLineWidth: 1, labels: { align: 'left', x: 3, y: -3 }, title: { text: 'My Chart' }, type: 'datetime' }, 
    yAxis: { labels: { formatter: function() { return this.value ; } }, title: { text: 'Battery Voltage (V)' } }, 
    series: [{ data: [['21/06/1392 09:02:32', 19.83], ['21/06/1392 11:02:32', 21.17], ['21/06/1392 13:02:31', 13.89], ['21/06/1392 15:02:31', 15.23]], name: 'Battery Voltage', type: 'line' }]
});
```

});

Comment: May you please share your project codes? Otherwise nobody can not help you.

Comment: I edited the post, sharing the resulting JavaScript code wish you can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to solve it,

In my particular case, I had to check if the timespan between two dataPoints is more than for example "2 Hours" , then I would add a DataPoint between those points and set it's value to Null.

Since I'm using DotNet.Highcharts, these steps are being performed using my MVC Controller logic.

```
 //dtValuesGrouped is a List of Type <DataValue> which is my Data Container class.

 SortedDictionary<string, double?> sortedDict = new SortedDictionary<string, double?>();
    if (dtValues[j + 1].DateTime - dtValues[j].DateTime> TimeSpan.FromHours(2))
    {
        sortedDict.Add(
            (dtValuesGrouped[j].DateTime+ TimeSpan.FromHours(1.5)),
            null);
    }
    sortedDict.Add(
            dtValuesGrouped[j].DateTime,
            dtValuesGrouped[j.Value);

 // and I will finally convert the sortedDictionary to an array of object[,] and set it to Chart.Serries.Data
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if you insert null values for those data points and make sure connectNulls is set to false.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-connectnulls-false/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                // connectNulls: false // by default
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, null, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've done that, the data is retrieved from database, if there is a data but no DataValue (i.e. null), that works fine, but the problems is sometimes there is no Data for more than 2 days. I want to cut off the chart, if the datetime interval exceeds a specific time span (e.g. 2 days).

Comment: also please note that my chart xAxis type is datetime, not categories

Comment: Except connectNulls, only what you can do is prepareing correct data in preprecessin, before push to data object.